Selective deployment o pipelines in azure synapse analytics using azure devops CI/CD
I had a requirement of implementing a Selective deployment of azure synapse analytics pipelines from one env.to other (DEV to QA) using azure devops CI/CD, git.I have tried to implement it using arm templates but my bad its taking entire set of workspace if there is one change in pipeline.
I tried this in ADF using ADF tools and it works as expected but on azure synapse analytics it doesn't work.Is there a way to cherry pick/selective deployment in azure synapse analytics and how to achieve the same.
